# EmberJS custom attr transform to serialize an array of custom objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using:

```
Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
```

I've got a model built around a list of custom objects that are serialized ans deserialized using a custom transform. It looks like this :

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('list', {
  serialize: function(value) {
    return value.mapProperty('line').join("\n");
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return (value || '').split(/\n/).
      map(function(line) { return App.ListItem.new(line: line); });
  }
});
App.ListItem = Ember.Object.extend({
  line: ''
});
App.MySuperModel = DS.Model.extend({
  list: DS.attr('list');
});
```

It works alright, the model gets dirty when I add or remove items in the list, but when I update a ListItem's line it doesn't get dirty nor return to its previous state when I rollback the transaction.

Has anyone any idea on how to get it to work ? I'd rather not use relationships for what is just a simple list and is persisted as such on my server.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to work around it, though I would still appreciate a cleaner method would anywone provide one.

What I did wrong was : I was manipulating the original array of lines, adding or removing lines, so ember didn't detect any change (no **.set('lines', ...)**) and it was rolling back to the original array that had been changed.

What I'm doing now is making a a new array of lines (using the handy **.copy()** method) and use **.set('lines', ...)** to tell my model its lines value has changed.

*(conclusion : sleep on your problems, they tend to solve themselves ^^)*